# Creating a function that iterates through a dictionary and returns the values of the keys inputed in the arguments

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create a function that prints the values of the keys in the dictionary. The function needs to take any number of key arguments and print the values of those keys. The only thing I'm struggling with is making the function take any number of keys as arguments.

Here's my code so far:

```
def print_values_of(dictionary, *keys):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        values = print(f"{value}")
        return values

simpson_catch_phrases = {"lisa": "BAAAAAART!", 
                     "bart": "Eat My Shorts!", 
                     "marge": "Mmm~mmmmm", 
                     "homer": "d'oh!", 
                     "maggie": "(Pacifier Suck)"
                     }

print_values_of(simpson_catch_phrases, "lisa", "marge", "homer")
```